# Using Microsoft's Emotion API to detect emotions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have not programmed a lot in JavaScript and I am hoping to improve myself. Thus, **I am looking for a style review** as well as to look for a better way to approach this problem (the current code works perfectly and as expected). What I am doing is requesting the Microsoft Emotion API to take an image and spit back the average happiness of all detected faces in the picture.

The code below is a small part of my project. Normally in other languages, I like to separate my code into as many small chunks as possible, but I am not so sure if I am doing it correctly here.

1. Would a class be suitable? Should I just write a function that takes two keys instead?
2. Should I have `this` all other the places?

Beside these questions above, I am sure that my code has many other problems. Also, I am building a Node server, so I could not use `export default`

```
const RapidAPI = new require('rapidapi-connect');

class ImageFaceEmotion {

  constructor(rapidKey, microsoftKey) {
    this._rapidKey = rapidKey;
    this._microsoftKey = microsoftKey;
    this.rapid = new RapidAPI('MLHPrimeMeme', rapidKey);
  }

  /* Returns a Promise with the overall happiness of the faces in the provided image.
  *
  * - url: link the the image
  */
  getEmotionFromImage(url) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      this.rapid
        .call('MicrosoftEmotionAPI', 'getEmotionRecognition', { 
          'image': url,
          'subscriptionKey': this._microsoftKey
        })
        .on('success', (payload) => {

          if (payload.length === 0) {
            reject('Cannot find any face within the picture');
          }

          let average = (payload.map(face => face.scores.happiness).reduce( (acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0)) / payload.length;
          resolve(average);
        })
        .on('error', (payload) => {
          reject(payload);
        });

    });
  }

}

var ifm = new ImageFaceEmotion('key1', 'key2');

ifm.getEmotionFromImage('link')
  .then((average) => {
    console.log(average);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

exports.ImageFaceEmotion = ImageFaceEmotion;
```

Comment: It does work. If it doesn't, this post should be on StackOverflow instead. As I have mentioned in the question, _I am looking for a style review_.